# 2D array value are passed like array and 0 do not get printed

Tags: c++

I'm working on this code and I don't understand why reading a matrix from the file doesen't output the correct matrix but instead it just shoves all the values != 0 into a single array and doesen't print 0. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

#define M 4
#define N 4

int** inputArray();
void printArray(int** matrix);

int main()
{
  int **matrix;
  matrix = inputArray();
  printArray(matrix);
  return 0;
}

void printArray(int** matrix)
{
for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int** inputArray()
{
int** matrix=new int*[N];
int value;
ifstream matrice("matrix.txt");
    if (matrice.is_open())
    {
        do
        {
            for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
            {
                matrix[i]=new int[M];
                for(int j=0; j<M; j++)
                {
                    matrice >> matrix[i][j];
                    //cout << matrix[i][j];
                }
            }   
        } 
        while (matrice>>value);
        matrice.close();
        return matrix;
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

The matrix I tried using is:
3418
0163
0023
0001

The program should print out exactly the matrix I'm reading from the file.

Comment: Is `3418 0163 0023 0001` exactly what you have in your file? What is the output of the program? I suppose it is `3418163231`. The `matrice >> matrix[i][j];` reads chars until whitespace (or EOL, not sure here), but not a single character like you seem to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input processing way is wrong ! As each element in a row is not separated by space you should take input as string or character.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

#define M 4
#define N 4

int** inputArray();
void printArray(int** matrix);

int main()
{
  int **matrix;
  matrix = inputArray();
  printArray(matrix);
  return 0;
}

void printArray(int** matrix)
{
for (int i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int** inputArray()
{
   int** matrix=new int*[N];
   int value;
   ifstream matrice("matrix.txt");
    if (matrice.is_open())
    {

            for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
            {
                string x;
                matrice>>x;
                matrix[i]=new int[M];
                for(int j=0; j<M; j++)
                {
                     matrix[i][j]=x[j]-'0';
                    //cout << matrix[i][j];
                }
            }

        matrice.close();
        return matrix;
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

I used string here. matrice>>x will take input until it get white space or newline.So matrice>>x will input a whole row as string in x. After taking input I iterated through the string and converted each character to number using x[j]-'0' and added each element on its cell.

Comment: Could you add some explanation to why `x[j]-'0'` works ? It'll make the answer clearer to the OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I knew I was doing something wrong with the load of the data from the file. In a previous version of the file I was using  `getline ` and parsing the data into a 2D array. But to be able to get that array out of a function I needed to switch to pointers and I got lost.